# Validation of ICD10-GM codes fails for specimen diagnosis

Tags: java, validation, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I get these error message when I'm trying to validate ICD10 (german version) codes in the specimen profile. I use the HAPI FHIR library for validation and validate angainst the bbmri.de implementation guide [specimen profile](https://simplifier.net/BBMRI.de/Specimen/%7Eoverview).

```
Bundle.entry[6].resource.ofType(Specimen).extension[2].value.ofType(CodeableConcept).coding[0] slicing-1: 'When slice no-icd is present, the other slices must not be present' Rule 'When slice no-icd is present, the other slices must not be present' Failed
Bundle.entry[7].resource.ofType(Specimen).extension[2].value.ofType(CodeableConcept).coding[0] Validation failed for 'http://fhir.de/CodeSystem/dimdi/icd-10-gm#C34.9'
Bundle.entry[7].resource.ofType(Specimen).extension[2].value.ofType(CodeableConcept).coding[0] slicing-1: 'When slice no-icd is present, the other slices must not be present' Rule 'When slice no-icd is present, the other slices must not be present' Failed
Bundle.entry[9].resource.ofType(Specimen).extension[2].value.ofType(CodeableConcept).coding[0] Validation failed for 'http://fhir.de/CodeSystem/dimdi/icd-10-gm#C78.0'
```

Here is one specimen resource from the json file I am trying to validate:

```
"resource": {
        "resourceType": "Specimen",
        "id": "pat0-specimen0",
        "meta": {
          "profile": [
            "https://fhir.bbmri.de/StructureDefinition/Specimen"
          ]
        },
        "extension": [
          {
            "url": "https://fhir.bbmri.de/StructureDefinition/Custodian",
            "valueReference": {
              "reference": "Organization/Tumor"
            }
          },
          {
            "url": "https://fhir.bbmri.de/StructureDefinition/StorageTemperature",
            "valueCodeableConcept": {
              "coding": [
                {
                  "system": "https://fhir.bbmri.de/CodeSystem/StorageTemperature",
                  "code": "temperatureLN",
                  "display": "Liquid nitrogen"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "url": "https://fhir.bbmri.de/StructureDefinition/SampleDiagnosis",
            "valueCodeableConcept": {
              "coding": [
                {
                  "system": "http://fhir.de/CodeSystem/dimdi/icd-10-gm",
                  "code": "C50",
                  "display": "Bösartige Neubildung der Brustdrüse [Mamma]"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "status": "available",
        "type": {
          "coding": [
            {
              "system": "https://fhir.bbmri.de/CodeSystem/SampleMaterialType",
              "code": "tissue-ffpe",
              "display": "Tissue FFPE"
            }
          ]
        },
        "subject": {
          "reference": "Patient/pat0"
        },
        "collection": {
          "collectedDateTime": "2021-11-19T13:44:13+01:00",
          "fastingStatusCodeableConcept": {
            "coding": [
              {
                "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0916",
                "code": "NG",
                "display": "Not Given - Patient was not asked at the time of the procedure."
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Can someone tell me if I am doing something wrong or is it a problem with the profile definition? The other ressources of the bbmri IG are working fine.

Answer (score -1):

This constraint: "no-icd.exists().not() or (icd-10-who.exists() or icd-10-gm.exists() or icd-9.exists()).not()" is broken.

There are not (and cannot be) any elements in the resource with the names "no-icd" or "icd-10-who", etc.  Constraints can't be tied to slice names, only to actual data within the instance.  You'd have to say something like:

code.coding.where(system="123" and version="456").exists()

Also, in looking at your profile, I don't see fixed values being declared for system or version, which are your discriminators.  (Discriminating by $this for a type of Coding also doesn't make sense.)

Comment: So the problem is in the definition of the specimen profile? I did not create the profile, I just use it to transform my data into FHIR to store it in a FHIR store. In this case I have to inform the creator of the profile.
Thanks for your quick answer!